# Jitpack inactive Subscription issue

Tags: android, sdk, gradle-plugin, jitpack

I published an andorid SDK on Jitpack. I am facing issues with my subscription. Despite making a payment, my subscription remains inactive. This is affecting my project.
I paid for monthly subscription but it is still Inactive.

[image]